# TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined - Unsure of how to fix

Tags: node.js, discord.js

OK, So I understand that I may need to add an if(!filter) type command into the following, but I'm not sure where or how.

The code file is:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const config = require('../settings/config.js');
const client = require('../index.js').client;
const Guild_ID = require('../settings/configuration').BOT_SETTINGS;
const totalUsers = client.channels.fetch('859879787614437427');
const onlineUsers = client.channels.fetch('859879824403202059');
const onlineStaff = client.channels.fetch('859879875531374672');

client.guilds.fetch('802700035544317972')
  .then(guild => console.log(guild.name))
  .catch(console.error);

setInterval(function() {
  console.log('Getting stats update..')

  var userCount = client.memberCount;
  var onlineCount = client.members.filter(m => m.presence.status === 'online').size
  var coderCount = client.roles.get('802711739006582846').members.size;
  
  console.log("Total Users: " + userCount);
  console.log("Online Users: " + onlineCount);
  console.log("Online Staff: " + coderCount);

  totalUsers.setName("Total Users: " + userCount)
  .then(newChannel => console.log(`Stat channel renamed to: ${newChannel.name}`))
  .catch(console.error);

  onlineUsers.setName("Online Users: " + onlineCount)
  .then(newChannel => console.log(`Stat channel renamed to: ${newChannel.name}`))
  .catch(console.error);

  codeMonkeys.setName("Online Staff: " + coderCount)
  .then(newChannel => console.log(`Stat channel renamed to: ${newChannel.name}`))
  .catch(console.error);
  }, 30000)
;
```

My error message is:

```
Getting stats update..
[Error] An exception happened in process: 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/container/events/Stats.js:17:36)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)
```

I have half an idea of the fix, but not sure of the actual execution therof.  Any assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Discord.js, as of version 12.0.0, only provides a premade property of `client.members` for members who are **cached** by Discord. Users who are not cached would have to be fetched and resolved as the `fetch()` method returns a promise.

As for your question, this property is accessible using its key `cache`.

```js
var onlineCount = client.members.cache.filter(m => m.presence.status === 'online').size
```

As a side note, please train yourself to use `let` and `const` when `var` is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Read the error carefully, it's not `if(!filter)` you need to check. It's something that you're trying to filter that is `undefined`.

In your case this is the culprit line:

```js
var onlineCount = client.members.filter(m => m.presence.status === 'online').size
```

It seems that the `client.members` is undefined at this point in time.

A simple solution is to check if members exist before filtering:

```js
if(client.members !== undefined) {
// I'm also guessing this is an array, the right property to get array size is .length
var onlineCount = client.members.filter(m => m.presence.status === 'online').length
}
```

### Edit

I've took a quick look at [`discord.js` API](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/search?query=client.members)(assuming you're using it), and I couldn't find any `members` property on `client` object. Are you trying to get the members of a guild maybe?

Comment: I don't have an If function in the code at the moment; do I need to be adding one?
Have edited post to include full error from console

Comment: That's not a function, that's the if statement + expression, I'll edit for clarity.

Comment: Essentially I followed a tutorial that means that it should automatically update specific channels to update the total number of server members, total online, and staff currently online.  (I will expand at a later point once I have the basics down!)

Comment: Feel free to edit the question with a link to the tutorial, that will help narrowing down the issue.

Comment: The original tutorial I followed was this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k9fqGh5Cr5s